# How to store and serve data and its progress over time in GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, wfs, features, time, versioning

I recently started working with [GeoServer](http://www.geoserver.org) and stored some shapefiles. I successfully can retrieve the data as JSON. The data I want to maintain in the database changes over time. I do **not want to update the values** but **add a new revision with a time stamp** of the very same data. Further, in the query reply I would like to see **all revisions of one feature being returned**.

**Question:** How can I store and serve various revisions of the same data with GeoServer?

---

**Update:** I am also interested in **other software** that fulfils the requirement to serve geospatial data with the versioning feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the answer to my question is the [WFS Versioning project](http://geoserver.org/display/GEOS/Versioning+WFS). Sebastian Benthall wrote about the topic [showing some visual examples](http://blog.opengeo.org/2009/03/17/versioning-vespucci/). Further work is discussed in the [GeoGit approach](http://geoserver.org/display/GEOS/GeoGit+approach). The user manual of the WFS Versioning extension can be found [here](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/extensions/wfsv.html) as well as a link to try it out!

I will explore the topics. Nevertheless, if somebody likes to **add practical experiences**, you are **very welcome** to extend this post!

---

**Update:** The project seems to paused at the moment due to the lack of funding (source IRC channel #geoserver).