# How to serve data that changes with time

Tags: mapserver

This question is practically the same as [an older one that concerns GeoServer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27594/how-to-store-and-serve-data-and-its-progress-over-time-in-geoserver); I'm interested in MapServer instead (and I don't see a satisfactory answer to the GeoServer question either).

I have some GeoTIFF files, each one being a temperature map at a specific time. Each hour I receive new data, so I create a new GeoTIFF file. I want the client to be able to ask the server for the list of times for which there is data. I can't understand how to do that.

I experiment with [WCS spatio/temporal indexes](http://mapserver.org/ogc/wcs_server.html#spatio-temporal-indexes), but `GetCapabilities` and `DescribeCoverage` don't seem to give me that information (I can't see the list of available data anywhere).

I'm not supposed to have a program modify the map file each time I get new data, am I?

Comment: Your link contains text "To-do Items and Known Limitations: MapServer does not derive all of the metadata it could from a given dataset. For example, you must explicitly list time periods covered by a layer. This should get better with time." Clearly there is no mechanism for updating time range automatically. I have never used WCS with Time but it looks like there should be a procedure for feeding times into the layer metadata item "wcs_timeposition". Or it could be "wcs_timeposition" "auto" when the tileindex layer would be scanned for capturing min/max from the "wcs_timeposition".